# Flask-Restless Marshmallow serializer

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I'm trying to exclude columns in a **Flask-Restless** API using a custom deserializer with **Marshmallow** as suggested by the [docs](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#serialization):

**serializers.py**

```
class HeatSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    heat_index = fields.Integer()
    updated_at = fields.DateTime()

class Meta:
    exclude = ('updated_at',)

def make_object(self, data):
    print 'Making object from', data
    return Heat(**data)
```

**server.py**

```
from serializers import HeatSchema

heat_schema = HeatSchema()

def heat_serializer(instance):
    return heat_schema.dump(instance).data

def heat_deserializer(data):
    return heat_schema.load(data).data

apimanager = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)

apimanager.create_api(
    heat,
    methods=['GET'],
    url_prefix='/api/v1',
    collection_name='heat',
    results_per_page=10,
    serializer=heat_serializer,
    deserializer=heat_deserializer
)
```

I get the same response from the API regardless of what I do with the Heat schema. I can put

```
blahblah = fields.Integer()
```

without any change. I can't even hit a breakpoint in the serializer while debugging so I assume I have this setup incorrectly with Flask-Restless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also experienced the same problem.
It seems that the behaviour appears only for GET_MANY functions.
If you try to GET a single object instance it should be compliant with the marshmallow schema.
This is a strange behaviour that's been reported here on the Flask-restless bug tracker:
https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/167

There the user *itsrifat* offered the workaround to add a postprocessor:

```
person_schema = PersonSchema()
```

`def person_deserializer(data):`
    `return person_schema.load(data).data`

`def person_after_get_many(result=None, search_params=None, **kw):`
  `result['objects'] = [person_deserializer(obj) for obj in result['objects']]`

`apimanager.create_api(Person,methods=['GET', 'POST','PUT', 'DELETE'],`
    `postprocessors={`
     `'GET_MANY':[person_after_get_many]`
    `}`
`)`

Comment: There is also new style serializer classes for one and many objects serialization check here https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serialization.html . When I checked it, flask-restless was 1.0.0b1

Answer (score 0):

The Meta class supposed to be inside Schema class.

Meta: is where the configuration is added to the schema class.

```
 class HeatSchema(Schema):
     id = fields.Integer()
     heat_index = fields.Integer()
     updated_at = fields.DateTime()

     class Meta:
         exclude = ('updated_at',)

     def make_object(self, data):
         print 'Making object from', data
         return Heat(**data)
```